# How do I solder a Sparkfun breakout board to a shield?

Tags: arduino, soldering

I need to solder some breakout boards onto an Arduino shield.  What's the general procedure to do this?  Do I solder it onto a header?  Do I need any other mechanical connection or hold-down?

For example, I would like solder this gyro sensor onto this aeroquad shield:

gyro sensor: http://www.aeroquadstore.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=SEN-09801

aeroquad shield: http://www.aeroquadstore.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=AQ2-000

Comment: Links aren't getting me anywhere....

Comment: hmm, double-checked the links, they're working for me.  Perhaps its the https://?  It seems to work with plain http://, let me change to that.

Comment: Dur, I should have tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your question about soldering the gyro sensor to the aeroquad shield goes, if you look a the tiny picture on their website, in the center of the board there is a region marked "gyro".  You'll take the single inline pin strips (also pictured) and break off 7 pins as a group.  Then you'll solder the short end into the gyro board.  Then (unfortunately) it looks like you'll have to solder the gyro board into aeroquad.

As far as shields go, in my experience (Arduino Duemilanove) the spirit behind the shield concept is to allow them to stack up.  The aeroquad "shield" doesn't appear to allow this, so I imagine you'll want to get single inline headers and solder them into the aeroquad so you can plug in the Arduino.

So if you want to add more breakout boards, the general procedure would be to get the headers with the extra long pins, and put those through your protoboards so that other shields can stack on top of them.  This allows everyone access to the pins in the Arduino that they need.

Comment: IMO, being able to stack multple shields is a bit of a myth. Every shield is going to use different pins for different functions, sometimes can share same pins, sometime not. Fortuantely there's the "Arduino Shield List" site (http://shieldlist.org/) to help with comparing pin usage of different popular shields.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely something that someone will have to worry about if they think they can blindly stack shields.  Thanks for pointing that out.